# How to compare two string dates in Java?

Tags: java, string, date, calendar

I have two dates in String format like below -

```
String startDate = "2014/09/12 00:00";

String endDate = "2014/09/13 00:00";
```

I want to make sure startDate should be less than endDate. startDate should not be greater than endDate.

How can I compare these two dates and return boolean accordingly?

Comment: Convert them to an actual time-based representation and compare them instead.

Comment: With that particular date format, you don't need to parse the dates because the fields are already in most-to-least-significant order, but @Makoto has the right idea in general.  Plus, parsing the date will be robust against bad inputs.

Comment: See my answer for a working example.

Comment: I don't believe the marked duplicate is the same question, the link points to a higher-level question about technique/strategy and advantages/disadvantages.  This question asks for a code example of how to do it.

Comment: @user1445967 Agreed. I re-opened the Question. And provided [an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58281016/642706) using *java.time*. Thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Convert them to an actual `Date` object, then call `before`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd h:m");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(startDate).before(sdf.parse(endDate)));
```

Recall that `parse` will throw a `ParseException`, so you should either catch it in this code block, or declare it to be thrown as part of your method signature.

Comment: Thanks. It helps me a lot.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: FYI before() method returns a boolean

Answer (score 16):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes to parse the inputs into [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) objects by defining a formatting pattern with [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), and comparing by calling [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime)).

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

Define a formatting pattern to match your inputs.

Parse as `LocalDateTime` objects, as your inputs lack an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
String startInput = "2014/09/12 00:00";
String stopInput = "2014/09/13 00:00";

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm" );

LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse( startInput , f ) ;
LocalDateTime stop = LocalDateTime.parse( stopInput , f ) ;
boolean isBefore = start.isBefore( stop ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( start + " is before " + stop + " = " + isBefore );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/P8zTBx).

> 2014-09-12T00:00 is before 2014-09-13T00:00 = true

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android.]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: is there a way to compare string of different length, say start = "2019", end = "2020-02"?

Comment: @RayZ Yes. See the `Year` and `YearMonth` classes. For a year only, use January to get a year-month. I suggest you post your own Question on that. And answer it yourself if you figure it out.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a fully working demo. For date formatting, refer - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Dating {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String startDate = "2014/09/12 00:00";
        String endDate = "2014/09/13 00:00";

        try {
            Date start = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH)
                    .parse(startDate);
            Date end = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH)
                    .parse(endDate);

            System.out.println(start);
            System.out.println(end);

            if (start.compareTo(end) > 0) {
                System.out.println("start is after end");
            } else if (start.compareTo(end) < 0) {
                System.out.println("start is before end");
            } else if (start.compareTo(end) == 0) {
                System.out.println("start is equal to end");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Something weird happened...");
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your time format is wrong.  The `Y` I could forgive (but it won't be compatible with calendars that don't support week years), but the `DD` is outright incorrect.

Comment: @Makoto - Thanks for pointing the error. I appreciate it. I have fixed it now. Can you please undo the downvote ? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert to `Date` to compare:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
Date start = sdf.parse(startDate);
Date end = sdf.parse(endDate);
System.out.println(start.before(end));
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and safest way would probably be to parse both of these strings as dates, and compare them. You can convert to a date using a SimpleDateFormat, use the before or after method on the date object to compare them.

Answer (score 2):

### I think it could be done much simpler,

**Using Joda Time**

You can try parsing this dates simply:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
DateTime d1 = formatter.parseDateTime(startDate);
DateTime d2 = formatter.parseDateTime(endDate);

Assert.assertTrue(d1.isBefore(d2));
Assert.assertTrue(d2.isAfter(d1));
```

Comment: FYI: The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), its creator, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), having gone on to lead [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) defining the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8+. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Java8 date api sucks. I am still using Joda with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse your string representation into instance of `Date`. The invoke `getTime()` to get milliseconds. Then compare the milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class DateComparision
{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws AssertionError, ParseException
    {

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        //comparing date using compareTo method in Java
        System.out.println("Comparing two Date in Java using CompareTo method");

        compareDatesByCompareTo(df, df.parse("01-01-2012"), df.parse("01-01-2012"));
        compareDatesByCompareTo(df, df.parse("02-03-2012"), df.parse("04-05-2012"));
        compareDatesByCompareTo(df, df.parse("02-03-2012"), df.parse("01-02-2012"));

        //comparing dates in java using Date.before, Date.after and Date.equals
        System.out.println("Comparing two Date in Java using Date's before, after and equals method");

        compareDatesByDateMethods(df, df.parse("01-01-2012"), df.parse("01-01-2012"));
        compareDatesByDateMethods(df, df.parse("02-03-2012"), df.parse("04-05-2012"));
        compareDatesByDateMethods(df, df.parse("02-03-2012"), df.parse("01-02-2012"));

        //comparing dates in java using Calendar.before(), Calendar.after and Calendar.equals()

        System.out.println("Comparing two Date in Java using Calendar's before, after and equals method");
        compareDatesByCalendarMethods(df, df.parse("01-01-2012"), df.parse("01-01-2012"));
        compareDatesByCalendarMethods(df, df.parse("02-03-2012"), df.parse("04-05-2012"));
        compareDatesByCalendarMethods(df, df.parse("02-03-2012"), df.parse("01-02-2012"));

    }

    public static void compareDatesByCompareTo(DateFormat df, Date oldDate, Date newDate)
    {
        //how to check if date1 is equal to date2
        if (oldDate.compareTo(newDate) == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(df.format(oldDate) + " and " + df.format(newDate) + " are equal to each other");
        }

        //checking if date1 is less than date 2
        if (oldDate.compareTo(newDate) < 0)
        {
            System.out.println(df.format(oldDate) + " is less than " + df.format(newDate));
        }

        //how to check if date1 is greater than date2 in java
        if (oldDate.compareTo(newDate) > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(df.format(oldDate) + " is greater than " + df.format(newDate));
        }
    }

    public static void compareDatesByDateMethods(DateFormat df, Date oldDate, Date newDate)
    {
        //how to check if two dates are equals in java
        if (oldDate.equals(newDate))
        {
            System.out.println(df.format(oldDate) + " and " + df.format(newDate) + " are equal to each other");
        }

        //checking if date1 comes before date2
        if (oldDate.before(newDate))
        {
            System.out.println(df.format(oldDate) + " comes before " + df.format(newDate));
        }

        //checking if date1 comes after date2
        if (oldDate.after(newDate))
        {
            System.out.println(df.format(oldDate) + " comes after " + df.format(newDate));
        }
    }

    public static void compareDatesByCalendarMethods(DateFormat df, Date oldDate, Date newDate)
    {

        //creating calendar instances for date comparision
        Calendar oldCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar newCal = Calendar.getInstance();

        oldCal.setTime(oldDate);
        newCal.setTime(newDate);

        //how to check if two dates are equals in java using Calendar
        if (oldCal.equals(newCal))
        {
            System.out.println(df.format(oldDate) + " and " + df.format(newDate) + " are equal to each other");
        }

        //how to check if one date comes before another using Calendar
        if (oldCal.before(newCal))
        {
            System.out.println(df.format(oldDate) + " comes before " + df.format(newDate));
        }

        //how to check if one date comes after another using Calendar
        if (oldCal.after(newCal))
        {
            System.out.println(df.format(oldDate) + " comes after " + df.format(newDate));
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Comparing two Date in Java using CompareTo method
01-01-2012 and 01-01-2012 are equal to each other
02-03-2012 is less than 04-05-2012
02-03-2012 is greater than 01-02-2012

Comparing two Date in Java using Date's before, after and equals method
01-01-2012 and 01-01-2012 are equal to each other
02-03-2012 comes before 04-05-2012
02-03-2012 comes after 01-02-2012

Comparing two Date in Java using Calendar's before, after and equals method
01-01-2012 and 01-01-2012 are equal to each other
02-03-2012 comes before 04-05-2012
02-03-2012 comes after 01-02-2012
```