# How to compare two dates in String format?

Tags: java, date, jodatime

What is the easiest way to compare two dates in String format? I would need to know if `date1` comes after/before `date2`.

```
String date1 = "2015-12-01";
String date2 = "2015-12-31";
```

Comment: Convert the strings to Dates and use those comparers.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963720/how-to-compare-two-string-dates-in-java)?

Comment: Why don't you convert them to Dates, then compare?

Comment: Actually, with that exact format, you need only do a string comparison

Comment: If it is an in example, with timestamp format (exact same format, date fields ordered by precedence, zero filled, and without overflowed values like `2015-11-35`) then you are good with string comparison, and this question is like asking about the color of the blue sky.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For a more generic approach, you can convert them both to `Date` objects of a defined format, and then use the appropriate methods:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Date date1 = format.parse(date1);
Date date2 = format.parse(date2);

if (date1.compareTo(date2) <= 0) {
    System.out.println("earlier");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In this very case you can just compare strings `date1.compareTo(date2)`.

EDIT: However, the proper way is to use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date d1 = f.parse(date1, new ParsePosition(0));
Date d2 = f.parse(date2, new ParsePosition(0));
```

And then compare dates:

```
d1.compareTo(d2);
```

The comparison will return negative value if `d1` is before `d2` and positive if `d1` is after `d2`.

Comment: Does not work to know which one comes before or after the other

Comment: Sure it does. In the format given, alphanumeric order equals chronological order.

Answer (score 4):

With JodaTime, simply:

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.parse(date1);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.parse(date2);

Assert.assertTrue(d1.isBefore(d2));
Assert.assertTrue(d2.isAfter(d1));
```

Answer (score 4):

I would advise you to convert them to `Date` objects.

```
String date1 = "2015-12-01";
String date2 = "2015-12-31";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(date1).before(sdf.parse(date2)));
```

Comparing them like:

```
if(date2 .compareTo(date1) > 0){
    System.out.println(" ---- ");
}
```

is not an ideal option (date1 and date2 are strings) as it loses the flexibility and can lead to its own share of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply convert your string to dates:

```
Date date1 = sdf.parse("2015-12-01");
Date date2 = sdf.parse("2010-01-01");
```

Then the comparison is done like:
    if(date1.after(date2)){
                System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
    }

```
if(date1.before(date2)){
            System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
}

if(date1.equals(date2)){
            System.out.println("Date1 is equal Date2");
}
```

If I remember correctly there's a `ParseException` to handle

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can compare this as follows:

```
Date date1 = new Date();
Date date2 = new Date();

if(date1.before(date2)){
    // statement
}

if(date1.after(date2)){
    // statement
}
```