# How to compare if a date is greater than other?

Tags: android, android-studio

> I am taking the current date in `ymd` format as below :

```
  String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

> I also have a date as String as below :

```
String futureDate = "2022-03-07"
```

> How can I know if the current date is less than or greater than future date ?

> I tried to use `compareTo()` function, but was unable to compare the two dates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963720/how-to-compare-two-string-dates-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare dates you can convert to `Date` and use:

```
final Date other = simpleDateFormat.parse("2022-03-07");
final Date now = new Date();

if (other.after(now)) {
    // In the future!
} else if(other.before(now)) {
    // In the past!
} else {
    // In the present!
}
```